# PDF generation in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf

After an upgrade to Rails 3.0.10 I have problems with PDF generation on Suse Linux. I use the flyingsaucer gem. The flying_saucer gem runs well in my Windows development/test environment (Glassfish 3.1.1 with war file deployment). However in the production environment (SUSE Linux and Glassfish 3.1.1) it generates a corrupted pdf file. Even if I downgrade Java to the version 6u30 I have the same problem.

Is there somebody who can recommend a running Linux/Rails3 solution to generate PDF using a html_to_pdf approach?

I have tried  acts_as_flying_saucer and wicked_pdf but was not able to get it running.